# Why is object returned from database call available only once?

Tags: node.js, database, object, asynchronous

I am running a database call (Node.js) using a promise as in my code below.  The call functions properly to return information from the database.  However I am immensely confused as to why I cannot then assign this value to another variable and access the information again?

My code:

```
app.post('/members/pages/callup', jsonParser, function (req, res) {

console.log("I RECEIVED FROM CLIENT THE FOLLOWING:");
console.log(req.body);

 db.lookupMember(req.body.name)
 .then(function(foundUser) {

 var user = foundUser;  //save the retrieved database info to a variable named 'user'... 
 console.log('Async success!', foundUser);  //prints to console fine, the info returned from database call
 console.log('Member Retrieved...' + user);  //prints [object, Object]  ...WHY...?????

  if (typeof foundUser != "undefined") {
  //do stuff
  }  //'foundUser' is NOT 'undefined'...

 })
 .catch(function(error) {
 console.log('UNABLE TO RETRIEVE MEMBER INFORMATION FROM THE DATABASE...' + error);
 res.redirect('/');  //route to splash page...
 });

})
```

Here is my output to illustrate my confusion...the value returned from the database call ('foundUser') prints to console just fine, however the assigned variable on the next line just prints 'object Object'...what is the reason for that?

```
I RECEIVED FROM CLIENT THE FOLLOWING:
{ name: 'Admin', presence: 'Yes', str: 'Some string: &=&' }
Async success! { email: 'me@somehost.com',
  username: 'Administration',
  service: 'unknown',
  status: 'active',
  login: '2019-12-9-13-52',
  legacy: '2019-12-9',
  hits: 0,
  token: 'UFei9NzA' }
Member Retrieved...[object Object]
```

Any information to clear up my confusion is appreciated.  I thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe it's cause you concat with a `+` in one and `,` in the other.. They are the same object though so the log shouldn't really matter. What are you trying to do after this?  Maybe log `user.username` instead.  That way you get a property instead of an object.

Comment: That was it...the "+" instead of the ","...thank you, nice catch.  I appreciate that.